# ASS/SSA Subtitle Style render

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

I need to parse style of captions that are ".ass" format. Right now I have a custom parser for ass subtitles and use `CaptionStyleCompat` for style change.

However, when I have two captions at once, style appends to both of them. Is there any way to append style for each cue?

Examples:

How it should be:
[image: How it should be]

How it actually appears:
[image: How it actually appears]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple:

1. Import ExoPlayer library as a module to your project ([guide](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/dev-v2/README.md#locally))
2. Go to `com.google.android.exoplayer2.text.Cue` and add `CaptionStyleCompat` variable
3. Go to `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.CanvasSubtitleOutput` and change `painter.draw` call to something like this:

```java
painter.draw(
         cue,
         cue.style, //This line exactly
         defaultViewTextSizePx,
         cueTextSizePx,
         bottomPaddingFraction,
         canvas,
         left,
         top,
         right,
         bottom);
```

4. Change the `TextOutput` interface in order to change the style of the cues. For example:

```java
newCue = newCue.buildUpon().setStyle(captionStyleCompat).build();
cues.set(cues.indexOf(cue), newCue);
```

Don't forget to set cues for player:

```java
playerView.getSubtitleView().onCues(cues);
```